# Move a div back and forth across page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to get a div to move from one end of the screen to the other on a loop. 
My javascript currently only attempts to move the div left but doesn't work.

```
    var func = function() {
       $("#bob").animate({"left": "-40px"}, 1000, function() { 
          $(this).animate({"left": "40px"}, 1000) 
       })

        setTimeout(func, 2000);
    }
```

Here is my jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/zsal/N48Eg/1/

Answer (score 4):

Name your functions, and then use one as the completion callback in the other:

```
function goLeft() {
    $('#bob').animate({'left': '-40px'}, 1000, goRight);
}

function goRight() {
    $('#bob').animate({'left': '40px'}, 1000, goLeft);
}

goLeft();
```

So, when it's done going left, it should go right. When it's done going right, it should go left.

Disclaimer: Untested

P.S. You're missing jQuery in your Fiddle.

Comment: I'm no expert on the how the call stack works in javascript, nor how jQuery calls these cabacks, but wont this just add more and more calls to the stack? Like very slow infinite recursion x) I'm not judging here, just curious :)

Comment: I don't think so. `animate` is asynchronous, so `goLeft` has already finished executing by the time `goRight` is executed as a callback from the animate function.

Comment: @ChristofferMansfield - There's a kind of logical recursion here, but no _actual_ recursion because all of the functions shown will be completely finished before the next is called asynchronously (by a timeout that jQuery uses behind the scenes). No function is ever waiting for another to return...

Comment: Thank you both for clearing that up, my curiosity is satisfied! :)

Answer (score 3):

Your current fiddle doesn't work because you didn't include jQuery (from the Frameworks & Extensions drop-down on the left) and because you define the `func()` function but never actually call it. Fix those two things and it will work as shown here: http://jsfiddle.net/N48Eg/8/

Note, however, that your animation code is more complicated than it needs to be. Multiple animations on the same element will be queued automatically by jQuery, so you don't need to use a callback on the first one to start the second. And you can supply `func` as the callback on the second and avoid the `setTimeout()` completely:

```
var func = function() {
    $("#bob").animate({"left": "-40px"}, 1000)
             .animate({"left": "40px"}, 1000, func);
}

func();
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/N48Eg/18/

Answer (score 0):

You just haven't called your function...

```
var func = function() {
    $("#bob").animate({"left": "-40px"}, 1000, function() { 
        $(this).animate({"left": "40px"}, 1000) 
    })
 setTimeout(func, 2000); // added back
}
func();
```

[Your updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/brbcoding/N48Eg/11/)

Answer (score 0):

First of, if you want the motion to continue, you need to use `setInterval` instead of `setTimeout`

Also you need to either move the `setInterval` out of the scope of `func`, or call `func` to start the animation

Answer (score 0):

lots of problems.  Heres a fiddle with a solution.

you also forgot to `position:relative` your absolutely positioned elements container.

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/N48Eg/7/)

you weren't calling your function for starters

i made a new one called `moveBob()`

Answer (score 0):

Here's the pure CSS version. http://jsfiddle.net/zDSRd/

```
#bob
{
    position:absolute;

    animation: fly 2s linear 0s alternate infinite;
    -webkit-animation: fly 2s linear 0s alternate infinite;
    -moz-animation: fly 2s linear 0s alternate infinite;
    -o-animation: fly 2s linear 0s alternate infinite;
    -ms-animation: fly 2s linear 0s alternate infinite;
}
@keyframes fly {
    from { transform: translateX(0px); }
    to { transform: translateX(500px); }
}
@-webkit-keyframes fly {
    from { -webkit-transform: translateX(0px); }
    to { -webkit-transform: translateX(500px); }
}
@-moz-keyframes fly {
    from { -moz-transform: translateX(0px); }
    to { -moz-transform: translateX(500px); }
}
@-o-keyframes fly {
    from { -o-transform: translateX(0px); }
    to { -o-transform: translateX(500px); }
}
@-ms-keyframes fly {
    from { -ms-transform: translateX(0px); }
    to { -ms-transform: translateX(500px); }
}
```